# How to keep a copy of latest code and release with github and bitbucket?

Tags: github, bitbucket

Our organisation has a contracting company working for them. The contracting company works on an app where the source code is on github and each release goes on bitbucket for deployment.

Our organisation also has a github account, and we would like to have the latest changes synced to our organisations github account.

For redundancy purposes, we would like to make sure if the contracting company disappeared with their github and bitbucket accounts, our organisation should not lose neither the code nor the artifacts generated for deployments.

I am not sure what I should be reading on as this is the first time I am seeing a problem like this, I have some simple knowledge of github and can find out more about bitbucket, but I am not sure what the concept is or which keywords I should be looking for.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I feel like this question is hard to answer because it's lacking of clarity. Can you try to be more specific? Are you looking for a way to clone the contents of a github and bitbucket account to another account or another machine?

Comment: @Gerald : cloned and updated when ever there is a change.

Answer (score 1):

I think a viable solution to this problem could be **periodically checking out the git repository** of the contracting company and checking it back in to your account if there is a change. A simple script could help doing that, let's say, once per day. Every commit will be mirrored, so you're not losing any data at all.

Maybe this script can give you an idea on how to accomplish this job:

https://gist.github.com/oweidner/6f173a9347f3b298dd0d